# HTML2canvas screenshot not working offline

Tags: javascript, openlayers, html2canvas

I want to be able to save my HTML2canvas map screenshot offline. Unfortunately, I am getting the console error:

**Uncaught TypeError: html2canvas(...).then is not a function
at makeScreenshot (index.html:143)
at HTMLAnchorElement. (index.html:155)**

Now, my code, which I picked up from here:

https://retifrav.github.io/blog/2018/07/23/html-js-screenshot/

looks like this:

```
  <script>
    function makeScreenshot()
   {
    html2canvas(document.getElementById("screenshot"), {scale: 2}).then(canvas =>
    {
        canvas.id = "canvasID";
        var main = document.getElementById("main");
        while (main.firstChild) { main.removeChild(main.firstChild); }
        main.appendChild(canvas);
    });
  }

 document.getElementById("a-make").addEventListener('click', function()
 {
    document.getElementById("a-make").style.display = "none";
    makeScreenshot();
    document.getElementById("a-download").style.display = "inline";
  }, false);

  document.getElementById("a-download").addEventListener('click', function()
  {
    this.href = document.getElementById("canvasID").toDataURL();
    this.download = "canvas-image.png";
  }, false);
    </script>
```

and in HTML body...

```
       </div>
       <div id="map">
       <div id="screenshot">
        <div id="popup" class="ol-popup">
            <a href="#" id="popup-closer" class="ol-popup-closer"></a>
            <div id="popup-content"></div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <a id="a-make" href="#">Make a screenshot</a>
        <a id="a-download" href="#" style="display:none;">Download a screenshot</a>
        </div>
```

The file html2canvas.js has been attached

```
      <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/html2canvas.js"></script>
```

[image]

Does anyone know where the problem can be?
I would like to make a screenshot offline

Comment: Which `html2canvas` library version you're using?

Comment: Good question. I've already uploaded the version v1.0.0, and it's fine. However console says: 
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null
referring to:

but this is for another thread I guess

Comment: Here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/dipakr13developer/pen/RwRObXZ) with your code and it's working without any issue.

Comment: Now I am getting:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toDataURL' of null at this.href = document.getElementById("canvasID").toDataURL();

Comment: Sorry my bad, I provided wrong id. When I provided a good ID then the console says: document.getElementById(...).toDataURL is not a function

Comment: Please check the codepen. There's some issue with your HTML container.